# Spring Security X-frame DENY

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Easy UI + Spring Security+ Spring Boot,

After I add OAuth2 settings to the project and the web pages retirn

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/vehicle/admin/index' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

I know it is because of the Spring Security frame options,

but I have tried to set the option to whether SAMEORIGIN or DISABLE, and it still doesn't work.

My webSecurityAdapter method configured as:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().and()
    .csrf().disable()
    .anonymous().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll();
}
```

UPDATE:

tried multiple http configuration but still doesn't work.

Code

```
@Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class TokenWebConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
     @Autowired
        private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

        @Autowired
        private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .csrf().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll();
        }
}


@Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class CommonWebConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
         @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                .antMatcher("/admin/**")
                .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
            }
    }
```

Comment: @dur Thats why I'm getting confused, it is still got deny instead of SAMEORIGIN. And I have tried different setting but got the same result

Comment: @dur Yes, I am sure. I am already using the /oauth/token to get the access token and the api urls are protect by the spring security framework.  Temporally I just work around using web configure to ignore those url from the security filters and it works